# Use timestamps to retrieve the most recent customer data from multiple tables in database

Tags: sql, timestamp, sybase

I have the four tables in a database:
 `CustomerMaster`,`Addresses`,`EmailAddresses`, & `PhoneNumbers`

`Addresses`,`EmailAddresses`, & `PhoneNumbers` reference `CustomerMaster`'s primary key.

I would like to create a query to get the most recent customer information for each customer in `CustomerMaster`. I know how to join the tables together but I don't know how to utilize the `TimeStamp` fields to retrieve only the most recently updated data from the `Addresses`,`EmailAddresses`, and `PhoneNumbers` tables for each customer in `CustomerMaster`.

**SQL Fiddle:** [`Working Example`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eaae8/1)

**CustomerMaster:**

```
 | CUS_PK | CUS_FirstName | CUS_LastName | CUS_AccountNum
 | 1      | mickey        | mouse        | 000001
 | 2      | donald        | duck         | 100000
```

**Addresses:**

```
 | ADD_CUS_FK | ADD_StreetAddress | ADD_City | ADD_StateProvince | ADD_PostalCode | ADD_TimeStamp
 | 1          | Disney World      | Orlando  | Florida           | 99999          | 2000-01-01 12:00:00.000
 | 1          | Disney Land       | Anaheim  | California        | 12345          | 2012-12-23 12:00:00.000
 | 2          | Disney World      | Orlando  | Florida           | 99999          | 2001-01-01 12:00:00.000
```

**EmailAddresses:**

```
 | EMA_CUS_FK | EMA_EmailAddress       | EMA_TimeStamp
 | 1          | supermouse@disney.com  | 2005-01-01 12:00:00.000
 | 1          | mousehouse@disney.com  | 2006-01-01 12:00:00.000
 | 2          | scrougeheir@disney.com | 2001-01-01 12:00:00.000
```

**PhoneNumbers:**

```
 | PHO_CUS_FK | PHO_PhoneNumber | PHO_TimeStamp
 | 1          | 999-999-9999    | 2001-01-01 12:00:00.000
 | 1          | 012-345-6789    | 2013-01-01 12:00:00.000
 | 2          | 666-867-5309    | 2001-01-01 12:00:00.000
```

**Query:**

```
 SELECT DISTINCT cm.CUS_FirstName, cm.CUS_LastName, cm.CUS_AccountNum,
 addr.ADD_StreetAddress, addr.ADD_City, 
 addr.ADD_StateProvince, addr.ADD_PostalCode,
 email.EMA_EmailAddress, phone.PHO_PhoneNumber
 FROM  CustomerMaster AS cm
 JOIN  Addresses AS addr
 ON    cm.CUS_PK = addr.ADD_CUS_FK
 JOIN  EmailAddresses AS email
 ON    cm.CUS_PK = email.EMA_CUS_FK
 JOIN  PhoneNumbers AS phone
 ON    cm.CUS_PK = phone.PHO_CUS_FK
 ORDER BY cm.CUS_AccountNum
```

**Current Result:**

```
Mickey | Mouse | 000001 | Disney World | Orlando | Florida    | 99999 | supermouse@disney.com  | 999-999-9999 
Mickey | Mouse | 000001 | Disney World | Orlando | Florida    | 99999 | supermouse@disney.com  | 012-345-6789
Mickey | Mouse | 000001 | Disney World | Orlando | Florida    | 99999 | mousehouse@disney.com  | 999-999-9999 
Mickey | Mouse | 000001 | Disney World | Orlando | Florida    | 99999 | mousehouse@disney.com  | 012-345-6789
Mickey | Mouse | 000001 | Disney Land  | Anaheim | California | 12345 | supermouse@disney.com  | 999-999-9999 
Mickey | Mouse | 000001 | Disney Land  | Anaheim | California | 12345 | supermouse@disney.com  | 012-345-6789
Mickey | Mouse | 000001 | Disney Land  | Anaheim | California | 12345 | mousehouse@disney.com  | 999-999-9999 
Mickey | Mouse | 000001 | Disney Land  | Anaheim | California | 12345 | mousehouse@disney.com  | 012-345-6789
Donald | Duck  | 100000 | Disney World | Orlando | Florida    | 99999 | scrougeheir@disney.com | 666-867-5309
```

**Desired Result:**

```
Mickey | Mouse | 000001 | Disney Land  | Anaheim | California | 12345 | mousehouse@disney.com  | 012-345-6789
Donald | Duck  | 100000 | Disney World | Orlando | Florida    | 99999 | scrougeheir@disney.com | 666-867-5309
```

How would I need to edit my existing query to get the desired result set?

Please provide an augmented SQL query (preferably a SQL Fiddle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, **[`LEFT JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)** and **`NULL`** checking was the solution:

**Query:**

```
 SELECT DISTINCT cm.CUS_FirstName, cm.CUS_LastName, cm.CUS_AccountNum,
 addrs1.ADD_StreetAddress, addrs1.ADD_City, addrs1.ADD_StateProvince,
 addrs1.ADD_PostalCode, email1.EMA_EmailAddress, phone1.PHO_PhoneNumber
 FROM  CustomerMaster AS cm

 JOIN       Addresses AS addrs1
 ON         cm.CUS_PK = addrs1.ADD_CUS_FK  
 LEFT JOIN  Addresses AS addrs2
 ON         cm.CUS_PK = addrs2.ADD_CUS_FK
 AND        addrs1.ADD_TimeStamp < addrs2.ADD_TimeStamp

 JOIN       EmailAddresses AS email1
 ON         cm.CUS_PK = email1.EMA_CUS_FK
 LEFT JOIN  EmailAddresses AS email2
 ON         cm.CUS_PK = email2.EMA_CUS_FK
 AND        email1.EMA_TimeStamp < email2.EMA_TimeStamp

 JOIN       PhoneNumbers AS phone1
 ON         cm.CUS_PK = phone1.PHO_CUS_FK
 LEFT JOIN  PhoneNumbers AS phone2
 ON         cm.CUS_PK = phone2.PHO_CUS_FK
 AND        phone1.PHO_TimeStamp < phone2.PHO_TimeStamp

 WHERE phone2.PHO_TimeStamp IS NULL
 AND   addrs2.ADD_TimeStamp IS NULL
 AND   email2.EMA_TimeStamp IS NULL
 ORDER BY cm.CUS_AccountNum
```

**SQL Fiddle:** [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eaae8/37)

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just use a subquery as a field in the select clause.  One subquery per table you want the most recent value from.  The subquery could be for example a "TOP 1" on descending timestamps.

Comment: Could you provide the modified query?